# Convert String to View in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller, controller

I have a framework which generating a jsp in a string variable, depends on parameters in json file.
How do I convert this string to jsp, return it from controller and render it?

In general. I have a table on the upper part of page. And after I click on a row, on the bottom part of the page I need to display the part of view generated in the controller "on the fly".

Comment: Don't you need anyone to understand your question! Please add some relevant clear details

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use some template engine for such tasks.

You see, jsp pages are not just a templates for population values into placeholders, in some moment they will be compiled to servlet-like java classes(could be on the first hit or precompiled when application starts or even compiled with project itself using build tool plugin) and from that moment on this compiled classes are responsible for all interaction, not a jsp engine.

Please try to explain *why* do you need such thing on a simple example, I'm sure it has to be another way for achieving this.